# Check type of a database field - python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, casting

I've a Django model which contains settings, so each element of the model is a setting and the possible fields are setting_name, setting_value, setting_type and so on.

For example, if I have a setting named **version** where the possible values are *integers* (like 1,2,3), the fields in the database are the following:

- setting_name = "version"
- setting_value = "2"
- setting_type = "int"

What I need to do is check if the value and the type of the settings are consistency between them.

With integers fields is not a problem because I'm able to cast the value to Int in order to check that.

But what about float and str? In the first case (Float) I don't want the automatically conversion in case the field contains an int (i.e "5" -> 5.0)

For the string, instead, the "cast approach" is not possible, because the field is always a string from database.

Any suggestions?

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.11

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you define a valid string?

Comment: @Harsh a simple text, not a json..

Answer (score 0):

you can make your model become like this:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, "Integer"),
        (2, "String"),
        (3, "Boolean"),
        (4, "Decimal")
    )
    key = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.TextField()
    value_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

you can also add class function in this model to return value as its type like this:

```
def get_typed_value(self):
    if self.value_type == self.INTEGER:
        return int(self.value)
    elif self.value_type == self.STRING:
        return self.value
    # ... do to other type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override save to check the consistency. A ValueError will be raised if type is invalid.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.setting_type == 'int':
        int(self.setting_value)
    # Checking int first to avoid treating floats as valid int type
    elif self.setting_type == 'float':
        float(self.setting_value)
    elif self.setting_type == 'string':
        # Logic for validating string here
    else:
        raise ValueError('Setting type not recognized' + self.setting_type)
    super(Setting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```